# Find the 100th derivative of a function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the $100$th derivative of $x^{1000}$

My attempt,

Let $y=x^{1000}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=1000x^{999}$

$\frac{d^{100}y}{dx^{100}}=901\cdot902\cdot...\cdot1000x^{900}$

I'm stuck at here. How to proceed ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that's it. You're done. You win.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976444/nth-derivative-of-xn-1

Comment: You're done. You could write the coefficient as $1000!/900!$ but that's not necessary.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/391/

Comment: Proceed to where?  The question is find the 100th derivative.  You found $\frac {d^{100}y}{dx^{100}}$.  Isn't that the 100th derivative? Why do you think you aren't done?

Comment: Unless it's supposed to be the $1000$-th derivative, in which case it's $1000!$.